# VSCode is not installed although I use the recommended rpm way - Fedoa 29

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

I use the described way for Fedora 29 but when I type sudo dnf install code I receive a long list of - nothing provides and , for example libgconf-2.5.4 (64 bit) ...etc etc.
I have tried to use nogpgcheck, but that also does not work.
If it is relevant when it starts after dnf check-update it says Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
I have previously installed VSCode on this laptop but then when I wanted to use another file, using File the path is shown a the top but there is no list of files. I then deleted VSode from the laptop and now I cannot install it again.
Thank you for your attention. I am awaiting your answer, thank you.
James Gibbens

Answer (score 0):

So, I use Fedora, and I always do it like so:

Go to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_rpm  (hopefully this triggers a download for you)

Then I just double click to install, through nautilus. That works like a charm for me. You should also be able to do `sudo dnf install code-*.rpm` in the command line, but I tend not to bother since I'm running gnome and chrome anyway, so it's pretty seamless to just use the UI provided.